# Disable or change port of dnsmasq service in libvirt

Tags: domain-name-system, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I'm using libvirt to manage my VMs, but I don't need the dnsmasq DNS server that gets automatically started with the service as it conflicts with my acme-dns setup.

Is there a way to change disable the DNS server completely and use dnsmasq only for DHCP, or at least change the port on which dnsmasq is listening?

Editing `/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf` has no point since it just get overridden, but when using `sudo virsh net-edit default` it's in a completely different format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable DNS for a network with `<dns enable="no"/>` in the network XML. See the [documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsAddress).

Answer (score 1):

No need to disable the dnsmasq service in the Libvirtd.
Just tell DNSMASK to listen on needed interfaces:

Edit

> /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Uncomment:

> bind-interfaces

Restart dnsmasq:

> systemctl restart dnsmasq.service

Additional informathion:
[Libvirtd and dnsmasq](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Libvirtd_and_dnsmasq)

This command may be useful. To check which interfaces used:

> netstat -anp | grep :53